# Displaying count for selected answers - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am designing a question and answer survey application for my students(multiple choice questions). Below is my model.

What i am trying to achieve is that, i am trying to group and count similar and non- answers submitted by students for a particular question.

For instance,

```
1. Gender 
   a) Male
   b) Female

2. Class
   a) Grade 4
   b) Grade 5

Sudent A selects 1.a  & 2.a

Student B selects 1.a & 2.b
```

In the instance above, both students selected Male for ques.1 but not the same answers for ques 2.

So i want to group and count similar and non-similar answers and display for each question on the response page.

After grouping and counting, i display my count on each and every question but with my code below on the response page, this is what i get

```
1. Gender  
    2
    1
    1 
   a) Male      
   b) Female

2. Class
    2
    1
    1 
   a) Grade 4
   b) Grade 5
```

NB: the 2,1,1 showing on my view means 2 answers are the same and other two (1,1) are not the same.

How can i make the count show on the respective questions like below

```
   1. Gender                       
      Male - 2

    2. Class                    
       Grade 4 - 1
       Grade 5 - 1
```

**Question**

```
class Question extends Model
{      
  public function survey() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
  }
  public function answers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
  }    
}
```

**Answer**

```
class Answer extends Model
{    
    public function survey() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
    }    
    public function question() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }}
```

**Controller**

```
//fetching and grouping same answers for particular question
$get_responses = DB::table('answer')
                   ->groupBy('question_id','answer')
                   ->select('answer', DB::raw('COUNT(answer) as selected'))
                   ->pluck('selected', 'answer')
    return view('answer.chart', compact('get_responses'));
```

**View**

```
 <div class="row">
            @foreach($surveys->questions as $question)
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h4 class="card-title">{{$question->title}}</h4>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content collapse show">
                  <div class="card-body">

                   @foreach($get_responses as $response)

                    <p>{{$response}}</p>


                   @endforeach


                  </div>
                </div>


            @endforeach
```